# cobertua instrumenting class

Tags: tomcat, instrumentation, cobertura

The steps that I followed to instrument the Cobertura

1. instrumenting the sources with cobertura
2. create war and deploy in tomcat
3. started the tomcat

Tomcat is  showing errors :

```
Mar 22, 2012 4:22:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 22, 2012 4:22:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

When excluding the listener still i am getting the above error.

I did some R & D and I found that classes having the import statement `com.XXX.ppl.servcies` making the listener fail. When I exclude them the tomcat is working well.

My problem is  there are many classes which have the above statement.
Is there  any solution for it?

Comment: and it works, when you don't istrument you classes? Are you sure that this is related to cobertura?

Comment: yes,normal war(With out coberutra instrumentation) is working well

Comment: do you have any stacktraces? This information is not enough to help :(

Comment: no i donot have stacktraces @Oers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried cobertura instrumentation in java 1.7 version.when i reverted back to java 1.6 cobertura worked 5ne.

i forgotten that cobertura doesnot work with java 1.7 version

Answer (score 0):

Before instrumenting once check the Cobertura.jar file was properly placed on your application
or not .
It should be in your application lib.
Check your java version.